# Item yield through a visitor page in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I spent my whole sunday struggling to get a proper response from [this website](https://mapa.aji-france.com/mapa/marche/) with Scrapy.

This is a website containing tenders: I want to get the name of the "Etablissement" (`entity`) by fetching their respective url (for example `https://mapa.aji-france.com/mapa/marche/122942/show`) and scrape the content :

[image]

But sometimes, a "visitor page" is displayed so you have to click on the `Continuer la visite anonymement` button to get redirected properly.

The href of the button is `https://mapa.aji-france.com/mapa/guest/anonymous` : using `scrapy shell`, I can fetch the tender using that url.

The code below doesn't work, and I really don't know how to handle this behaviour!

Many thanks for your help

```py
import scrapy

BASE_URL = "https://mapa.aji-france.com/"

class TendersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tenders_spider"
    allowed_domain=[BASE_URL]
    start_urls = [
        'https://mapa.aji-france.com/mapa/marche/',
    ]
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            self.start_urls[0],
            callback=self.crawl_tenders
        )

    def crawl_tenders(self, response):
        for tender in response.xpath("//div[@class='card mb-2']"):
            reference = tender.xpath("./div/i/text()").get()
            
            yield response.follow(
                "/mapa/guest/anonymous",
                callback=self.parse_tender,
                dont_filter = True
            )
           
            
    def parse_tender(self, response):
        success_xpath = "//div[@class='card-header bg-success text-white']"
        warning_xpath = "//span[@class='fa fa-eye-slash']/parent::a/@href"
        if response.xpath(success_xpath):
            yield {
                'entity': response.xpath("//div[normalize-space()='Etablissement']/following-sibling::div//td").get()
            }
        elif response.xpath(warning_xpath):
            url = response.xpath(warning_xpath).get()
            yield response.follow(
                "/mapa/guest/anonymous",
                callback=self.parse_as_anonymous,
                dont_filter = True
            )
        else:
            yield {'entity': "Can't find success or warning xpath."}
            
            
    def parse_as_anonymous(self, response):
        if response.xpath("//div[normalize-space()='Etablissement']"):
            yield {
                'entity': response.xpath("//div[normalize-space()='Etablissement']/following-sibling::div//td").get()
            }
        else:
            yield {'entity': "Can't find in visitor modes"}
```

Comment: Do you have any reasons to use `asyncio`, instead of default `twisted` reactor? Scrapy is async by default. Also, if you're using `asyncio`, where are you awaiting variables/results?

Comment: Just changed it (...as I used to try something with `Playwright`).
Yet, it does not work any better.

Comment: Maybe you can inspect the network call made by that button (asking you to confirm you're navigating anonymously) and include that url in Scrapy start_urls.. or call that link every time you process a tender card, before accessing it's detail page. I'm sure you can implement such solution without me writing it.

Comment: Thank you Barry. I found the same url that I already have using the network inspector, so no changes. I may lack of knowledge however, or misunderstood your point.

Comment: Just add a rule, or a simple if/else block - if response text contains this href: `/mapa/guest/anonymous` (or something unique to that page asking you to register) then just do another call to `https://mapa.aji-france.com/mapa/guest/anonymous` and you should get your page.

Comment: This is what I tried to do on this line : `elif response.xpath(warning_xpath):`. warning_xpath check indirectly for `/mapa/guest/anonymous`.

Comment: Hi @BarrythePlatipus, seems like most of the calls are redirected [302] after yielding the first function. So I tried another way of parsing by avoiding redirection. Not succesfully... I am so stuck, any kind of help would be appreciated as my deadline is coming fast.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll check the network tab from the website, you'd find that the subsequent `/mapa/guest/anonymous` calls contain a cookie that is used to create the very next call to the show page.

[image]

You'll be able to scrape items, once you enable cookies in your spider. The cookies can be enabled by setting the `COOKIES_ENABLED` setting to `True`.

You can do this in the spider itself by defining the `custom_setting` variable as

```
...

custom_settings = {
    "COOKIES_ENABLED": True
}

...
```

Or you can simply define the setting in your project's `settings.py` if you don't have issues setting it globally.

You can find more about this setting [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#cookies-enabled).

Comment: Roger that,, I will try that, thank you so much.

Comment: Spent another 3 hours, it doesn't seem to work either, BUT I found a `verify_credentials` lower in the network list. However, it confuses me even more about the approach to take.

Comment: What do you get? Are you getting the same redirections or what responses are you getting? It'll be great if you could provide the full crawl response in a Pastebin link or something like that.